# Use data from two locations in Firebase, reading data simultaneously

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to read data from two database locations, and then use these bits of data in a function. The way I am doing it currently is this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/data/').once('value').then(function(data1) {
  firebase.database().ref('/datatwo/').once('value').then(function(data2) {
       //Here i can use data1.val() and data2.val()
    });
});
```

However, I understand that this only begins reading `/otherdata` after the first piece of data has finished retrieving. Is there a way to simultaneously download these two pieces of data and use them in a function one both are complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.all()`:

```
Promise.all([
  firebase.database().ref('/data/').once('value'),
  firebase.database().ref('/datatwo/').once('value')
]).then(function(results) {
   var data1 = results[0],
       data2 = results[1];
   //Here you can use data1.val() and data2.val()
});
```